# How to put a visualization in elasticsearch directly?

Tags: elasticsearch, visualization, kibana, elastic-stack

I was posting a question about the automatic (ie : scripted automation) creation of visualizations in Kibana. BUT I found the solution while writing it ;) Let me explain :

I was kind of blocked because I can't find nothing on the web about it. And the documentation of Elasticsearch doesn't explain that.

In a few words, the global projet I'm trying to do is to write a script to automatically create a new dashboard according to a specific user (for that, it is the search that changes).

More precisely, as a dashboard is made of visualizations, we need to create the visualizations in the first place. I was blocked at this step, creating the visualization directly via a CURL -XPOST request to ElasticSearch.

Because in order to do the final dashboard, we need to :

1. Write the search(es)
2. Create the visualization(s)
3. Create the dashboard made of visualizations

Schematically :

Input : Username --> Myscript --> Dashboard of the user

To make things clear, a visualization is only a JSON document in the path (in my case, but surely in yours too) :
'http://localhost:9200/.kibana/visualization/*'
In ElasticSearch.

So it's simple, add a new visualization as you add a new document through the ElasticSearch API.
To do that, and to know what the visualization you want to create looks like, you can create it using Kibana web interface; and once you validate and it's added in ElasticSearch, you see the ElasticSearch document.

Let's say we created a Pie Chart using Kibana named "Test1" : we request it in ElasticSearch to see the document.

```
curl -XGET 'http://localhost:9200/.kibana/visualization/Test1'
```

You should have this kind of result :

```
{"_index":".kibana","_type":"visualization","_id":"Test1","_version":1,"found":true,"_source":{"title":"Test1","visState":"{\"aggs\":[{\"id\":\"1\",\"params\":{},\"schema\":\"metric\",\"type\":\"count\"},{\"id\":\"2\",\"params\":{\"field\":\"type.raw\",\"order\":\"desc\",\"orderBy\":\"1\",\"size\":10},\"schema\":\"segment\",\"type\":\"terms\"}],\"listeners\":{},\"params\":{\"addLegend\":true,\"addTooltip\":true,\"isDonut\":false,\"shareYAxis\":true},\"title\":\"New Visualization\",\"type\":\"pie\"}","uiStateJSON":"{}","description":"","version":1,"kibanaSavedObjectMeta":{"searchSourceJSON":"{\"index\":\"logstash-*\",\"query\":{\"query_string\":{\"analyze_wildcard\":true,\"query\":\"YOUR KIBANA DISCOVER SEARCH HERE\"}},\"filter\":[]}"}}}
```

So, then, we want to create a similar document into ElasticSearch directly, without using Kibana, as we would need it in a script. The query looks like this :

```
curl -XPOST 'http://localhost:9200/.kibana/visualization/Test2' '{"title":"Test2","visState":"{\"aggs\":[{\"id\":\"1\",\"params\":{},\"schema\":\"metric\",\"type\":\"count\"},{\"id\":\"2\",\"params\":{\"field\":\"type.raw\",\"order\":\"desc\",\"orderBy\":\"1\",\"size\":10},\"schema\":\"segment\",\"type\":\"terms\"}],\"listeners\":{},\"params\":{\"addLegend\":true,\"addTooltip\":true,\"isDonut\":false,\"shareYAxis\":true},\"title\":\"New Visualization\",\"type\":\"pie\"}","uiStateJSON":"{}","description":"","version":1,"kibanaSavedObjectMeta":{"searchSourceJSON":"{\"index\":\"logstash-*\",\"query\":{\"query_string\":{\"analyze_wildcard\":true,\"query\":\"YOUR KIBANA DISCOVER SEARCH HERE\"}},\"filter\":[]}"}}'
```

That's it ! You can check the Pie Chart has been well created in Kibana ;)

Have a good day, I hope this has been useful.

Tony